# Grant execute gives Illegal Grant/Revoke command Error when run on table

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

Why didn't this work?
I have tried `GRANT`:

```
GRANT DELETE,INSERT,SELECT,UPDATE,TRIGGER,EXECUTE ON databasename.tablename
TO 'user123'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pas$-word11';
```

it's throwing back error:

> ```
> ERROR 1144 (42000): Illegal GRANT/REVOKE command; 
> please consult the manual to see which privileges can be used`
> ```

Comment: I think it started after I had made my first trigger in the database, but thought it wouldn't hurt with a execute grant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the EXECUTE privilege could not be run with any table specified, since the "level" is not aiming at table

(About grant Execute)

> Enable the user to execute stored routines. Levels: Global, database,
> routine.

[MySql ref manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)

I had to run EXECUTE separately with

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON tablename.* TO 'user123'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pas$-word11';
```